# How do I plot the cdf curve as line type and overlay it with ecdf curve?

Tags: r, plot, cdf, weibull, ecdf

Can anybody tell how can I put the two cumulative distribution curve in a same plot?

While executing this command:

```
plot(x,pweibull(x,shape=1.120662,scale=18.496778),type="l",col=4)
plot(ecdf(SIZEDIST$AVG.µm.),add=TRUE)
```

the Weibull cdf curve is appeared in some unexpected form. It is not what I was expecting.
I need the first curve as smooth line and the second ecdf curve as step.

Comment: Why did you ask this question [twice](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/22437380/)?

Answer (score 0):

Use function `lines`

```
plot(ecdf(rnorm(20)),col='red')
lines(ecdf(rnorm(10)),col='blue')
```