# How can I plot two cumulative distributions curve as line type in same plot

Tags: r, plot, cdf, weibull, ecdf

I want to plot cumulative distributions curve for Weibull distribution over empirical cumulative distribution curve.

I have tried with this several times but it does not serve the way I want. Here is the command:

```
x<-(SIZEDIST$AVG.µm.)
x
plot(x,pweibull(x,shape=1.120662,scale=18.496778),type="l",col=4)
plot(ecdf(x),add=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lines` instead of `plot`

```
plot(x,pweibull(x,shape=1.120662,scale=18.496778),type="l",col=4)
lines(ecdf(x),col='red')
```

Comment: hi. thanks for your comment. but while trying to execute the command it appears something unusual which I don't want. well the graphs are combined but the weibull cumulative curve appears as combination of plenty of polygons which is pretty unexpected. can u please update me. and also I'd like to know how can I change the appearance ecdf curve because it appears as lines studded with the points, whereas Ii want only the lines.

Comment: Could you paste reproductive example?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

[image]

```
set.seed(1)  # for reproducibility
# 1000 random samples from the Weibull dist
X <-rweibull(1000,shape=1.120662,scale=18.496778)
# z covers the range in X
z <- seq(min(x),max(x),length=100)
plot(z,pweibull(z,shape=1.120662,scale=18.496778),type="l",col=4, ylab="CDF")
plot(ecdf(x),add=TRUE)
```